# Band Name Grammar

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

If there is a name of a band, like *The Black Keys*, do you say "*The Black Keys* **are** awesome*" or "*The Black Keys* **is** awesome"?

Normally, you would say a band is 'they,' but then you would say 'they **are** awesome', but a band is one thing so you would say 'that band **is** awesome.' Which one is correct for a name like *The Black Keys*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Band* is a [collective noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun), and so is *The Black Keys*. In British English you can use either *is* or *are* (also, *was* or *were*), depending on how you view the noun. Plural verbs are more common overall.

If a collective noun is seen as a whole, sole, impersonal unit, then singular verbs are more common:

> If your band **isn't** this week's priority, you are probably going to be forgotten.
>
> The band **is made up of** two men.
>
> <sub>(From [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/))</sub>

If it is seen as a collection of people doing personal things, then plural verbs are more common:

> Meanwhile, the band **are** currently **working** on a third album to follow '91's ‘The Beast Inside’.
>
> Meanwhile, the band **are** currently **writing songs** for a new studio LP which will feature a host of guest vocalists — many of whom have been affiliated with The Pogues during their nine-year history.
>
> ‘This was about the time The Beatles **were** just starting and they were considered to have long hair, [...]
>
> The Rolling Stones **are fined £5 each** for urinating in a garage forecourt after a concert in Romford, Essex.
>
> <sub>(From [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/))</sub>
>
> Liverpool **are** winning.
>
> <sub>(From Collins COBUILD English Usage)</sub>

This affects the use of relative pronouns, too. When you see a collective noun as an impersonal unit, *which* is preferred, whereas if you see it as a collection of people, *who* is preferred.

> The committee, **who are** hoping to announce important changes, ...
>
> The committee, **which is** elected at the annual meeting, ...
>
> <sub>(from Practical English Usage, entry 526)</sub>

In American English the verb for the noun is usually singular in all cases except *family* (if you don't quantify it with *members of*, *people in* etc). However, plural pronouns with plural verbs can be used, so it is possible to find that one uses *the band is* and then refers back to the band as *they* (rather than *it*).

> "What's your name? " I ask her, as the other mothers pull their kids away, too, because a Jesus band **is singing** on the main stage and there's soon to be a raffle for a homemade quilt and a free rototilling.
>
> "**My family are** probably the oldest Shia family in Lebanon," she explains
>
> <sub>(From [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/))</sub>

Source: [Collins COBUILD English Usage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0007423748) and [Practical English Usage](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-English-Edition-International-Students/dp/0194420965)

Comment: Speaking as a native speaker of American English, I do not think there is an exception for "family" in this case. The example sentence seems foreign or wrong. "My family *is* probably the oldest Shia family in Lebanon" would be the unmarked American English way to say it.

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

> The Black Keys **is/are** awesome.

you are probably talking about the members of the band, so you should use *are*. But if you say:

> The Black Keys *band* **is** awesome.

then you would use *is*.

On the other hand,

> The members of the Black Keys **are** awesome.

The *band* is singular, and the *members in the band* are plural.

Comment: A useless answer - the question is not 'What is a plural?'