# How to refer to an entity composed of multiple persons (it or they)?

Tags: subjects

Suppose you have a team composed of several persons. If I want to designate this team without repeating "team", which word do I have to use ? "it" or "they" ?

In other words, which one of the following sentences is correct ?

> The team decides whether it wants to work on this project or not.
>
> The team decides whether they want to work on this project or not.

Maybe both are correct.

- In the first one, "it" stands for one single entity but associates
  the human sensation "I want to work on this project" whereas a team
  is not **a** human.
- In the second one, "they" implicitly stands for
  the members of the team but I am not sure of the correctness of "The
  team ... they ...".

I would very appreciate to have some feedback on those 2 formulations.

Comment: Relevant question on the ELU SE: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183101/germany-is-are-in-the-nato-alliance-clarification-please/183105#183105

Comment: Your question title is totally ambiguous. You need a "verb" after"*How to*".

Comment: @Neeku, fixed it.

Comment: Looks better now. (:

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24919/3281. That question came to mind immediately once I saw your question. Though the other question is about the subject-verb agreement, basically that question and this one ask the same thing, when a group of people is considered plural, and when singular.

Comment: Thanks for the links. So I guess that the 2 formulations are correct.
@Neeku Sorry for that, I didn't notice I forgot a word in the title.