# 'Team' doesn't or don't'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, singular-vs-plural

I have found that in BrE, 'the team' is either singular or plural, while in AmE, it is always singular from here: [Team as singular or plural](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71361/team-as-singular-or-plural)

I read the following line in the [article](http://www.firstpost.com/sports/first-test-preview-dry-mohali-pitch-should-favour-india-over-south-africa-2493984.html?utm_source=fp_top_internal):

> Given the right conditions, and the team playing to its potential, Kohli will be disappointed if his team ***don’t*** win the series.

Now, my question is: Should we put '**doesn't**' in place of '**don't**' as looking at the context, here 'team' looks singular? Why?

Comment: Do you want an answer for British English?  for Indian English? or for some other dialect?

Comment: @Jasper want an answer for Standard English.

Comment: Related: [Band Name Grammar](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24919/3281).

Answer (score 4):

Subject verb agreement.

'Team' is a collective noun and the beauty of this noun is it can have both -singular and plural verb!

Then, how to decide? Well, it depends on the context.

If you want the noun to act as one unit, use a singular verb.

> The ***team is*** on the ground.

In other case, if you want to be specific about **individuality**, use a plural verb. Say--

> The ***team are*** arguing among themselves over a trivial dispute

So, in the given sentence, the author probably focuses on the individuality.

The context is *cricket*, and the sport is *much* dependent on individual's performance that in turn strengthens the team. You often hear either bowlers or batsmen don't perform well and the team loses.

Comment: I like this way of doing it, but I've heard usages that violate it (in both directions). Is it a rule that many people seem to break, or are you simply making a (very sensible) suggestion?

Comment: English as a language has become quite flexible and in fact, that's the beauty of this language. Yes, what I wrote is standard, the way I read, learn and implement. There are many with other styles and you cannot call them utterly wrong! :) @WolfieInu

Comment: Fair enough! The way I was taught was that collective nouns are always singular, but your way makes some sense as well. But I confess that I cringe when I hear, for example, sports announcers deciding that "the German football team are very strong."

Comment: Exactly, they refer to each individual in the team, but collectively! @WolfieInu Wikipedia has the page on it that outlines this issue.