# Collective Nouns and their possessive pronouns

Tags: possessive-pronouns, collective-nouns

> 1. The crowd **is** clapping **their** hands.
> 2. The crowd **are** clapping **their** hands.
> 3. The crowd **is** clapping **its** hands.

Which one of the above is a correct sentence?

The word 'crowd', being a collective noun, can take a singular verb when the members of the group are doing the same thing at the same time.

Then, what about its possessive pronoun? Should it be **its** or **their** ?

This site [(dummies.com)](https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/how-to-select-pronouns-for-collective-nouns/) says "Body parts always belong to individuals, not to groups." It means that "their" is correct. But the site does not say about the verb whether it should be singular or plural in a sentence like the ones shown above.

Comment: [Here's an NGrams usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+crowd+was+shouting%2Cthe+crowd+were+shouting&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=1) for the American English corpus for the last  couple of decades, showing how even they are finally giving up that dogmatic  perspective *(it's **the / a** crowd, so it must be **singular**)*. When what the crowd are doing obviously involves lots of ***individuals*** doing it, Brits have always been inclined to treat ***crowd*** as ***plural***. And Americans are starting to follow suit.

Comment: Related (over on ELU): [*“On their **back**” or “on their **backs**”?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/on-their-back-or-on-their-backs)

Comment: There are two separate issues here: *crowd is* vs. *crowd are*, and *its hands* vs. *their hands*. Regarding the first, see *['Team' doesn't or don't'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72582)* and *[“India has” or “India have”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/)*.

Comment: I'd just say "the crowd is clapping"

Answer (score 1):

> > Which one of the above is a correct sentence?

I don't think a native English speaker would say any of these. This is often the case with these 'which is correct' questions... because there is a basic ambiguity. We would say, "The crowd is clapping." The 'hands' part is implied.

It needs to be 'The crowd is' never 'The crowd are', at least in American English. The same with 'The audience is'. But we would say 'The people are'.

Comment: I agree; however, the question is asking about 'crowd' as a noun and the appropriate verb tense and number agreement. "The crowd is waving its arms" would be grammatically correct, though it sounds a little awkward. And saying just "The crowd is waving" would leave it ambiguous *what* the crowd was waving, unlike clapping.

Comment: @rcook: Yes, this is exactly my question is about. Thank you.

Comment: @Vaughn Ohlman: **The audience was/were waving its/their hands.** Which is correct?

Comment: Awkward.

If I really wanted to say such a thing, I would probably add 'all'... thus, "The audience were all waving their hands."